# Rails 4 - Association between two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

New to Rails here; having trouble grasping how to model a relationship between two models:

- I have a **foods** model with fields: id, name, serving_size, calories
- I have a **units** model with fields: id, name

The units table simply contains rows for "grams", "cups", "millilitres"

I would like to associate the **units** table to the **foods** table. The goal being that if "serving_size" was say 100, then we would know whether it's ounces, grams or millilitres.

I have no idea how to do this

To start:

- Add a foregin key **unit_id** to **foods** (e.g. via **add_foreign_key** migration)

But I don't know what the proper way to go from here is? I could write methods that do raw SQL commands, but there must be an easier way

Can we accomplish this so that I can do something like: Food.find( name: 'milk' ).unit.name ?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: did you add `has_many` and `belongs_to` in model?

Comment: The problem is it's a one-to-one mapping. One record in "foods" represents one food item -- and therefore it will only ever have one "unit" (e.g. grams, oz, ml, etc.). I can add a unit_id column in foods.... but then what? @uzaif

Comment: did you add  unit reference  in food?

Comment: @Ricky will food have one unit or many unities ?

Comment: @7urkm3n They will only ever have one unit (so I can include a "unit_id" foreign key). But then I don't know how to model that relationship in Ruby

Comment: @Ricky you need to set it `#food.rb has_one :unit` then `#unit.rb belongs_to :food`.

Comment: Thanks. So if I add those associations, what difference will that make now? E.g. How will I set the food.unit_id afterwards? @7urkm3n

Comment: @Ricky Do you want to see example in a `controller` or `model` ? I can post both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your problem description I would do this differently. I'd run the following commands in the terminal

```
rails g model Unit name:string
rails g model Food name:string service_size:integer calories:integer unit:references
```

Rails will magically infer everything else.

That should create the migrations and models with the associations you need to assign a unit to a food. The interesting thing about this association that gets generated is that a food 'belongs_to' a unit and a unit 'has_many' foods. I did it this way so that many food records can share the same unit, rather than redundantly assigning the same unit through a new record for every food you create.

EDIT: If you want to access all food associated with a unit then you should add has_many :foods to the unit model.

Comment: Thanks! I'm testing this method. At first glance, I noticed the `belongs_to :unit` relationship exists in food, but the `has_many :foods` is NOT initially added to unit. Is this correct and OK? @hypern

Comment: That's true. It may not be necessary, but I would add that association to the unit model so that you can use all of the association methods it provides. Look at the methods it provides for a 'has_many' relationship [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)